# R ecdf function gives only 0 or 1 values

Tags: r, ecdf

my dataset consists of stock prices. My final goal is to fit for practice a copula to two stocks.

However, while trying to transform my data to a [0,1] scale with the ecdf function, I get a weird ecdf-plot for one stock.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hCgr.png)

The function works fine for the other stock.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMqfC.png)

I searched for dissimilarities in the data set, but both variables don't have missing values and consist only of numbers in string format.

The code:

```
DFM.roh <- read.xlsx("C:\\Users\\Simon\\Documents\\ML Seminar\\Deutscher Finanzmarkt Daten.xlsx")
DFM <- data.frame(X_bei = DFM.roh$s_bei, X_bayn = DFM.roh$s_bayn)

y_a <- ecdf(DFM$X_bei)(DFM$X_bei)
ecdfs_a <- sort(y_a, decreasing = FALSE)
plot(ecdfs_a)

y_b <- ecdf(DFM$X_bayn)(DFM$X_bayn)
ecdfs_b <- sort(y_b, decreasing = FALSE)
plot(ecdfs_b)
```

Data sample in R:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2ZLD.png)

Data samle in excel:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35l6W.png)

Comment: Could you include an exemple of your dataset DMF by editting your post ? Thanks (post the output of `dput(head(DFM)` for instance)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the problem consisted of 3 digit numbers with two decimal digits (instead of predominantly 4 digit numbers with two decimal digits). After replacing every figure by the equivalent number without strings and decimal digits, it worked.